# Flask dynamic route is taking values which I have not specified

Tags: python, flask, routes, dynamic-routing

**Question**

I have created a dynamic route as `/update/<randomString>` in my `Flask` app.py file, where `randomString` is a randomly generated string with the length of **50**. However if I search for `/update/1` I am able to view the same dynamic route `/update/<randomString>` without any error! Can anyone explain why is it so?

**See what I've tried so far:**

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
 randomString = ''.join(secrets.choice(string.ascii_uppercase+string.digits+string.ascii_lowercase) for k in range (50))
 session['randomString'] = str(randomString)
 return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/update/<randomString>')
def update(randomString):
 if 'randomString' in session:
  randomString = session['randomString']
  return render_template('update.html')
 else:
  return 'error...'
```

*Link of the dynamic page at update.html page, where random string is passed with the help of session(defined at index.html page).*

```
<a href="update/{{randomString}}">Dynamic page</a>
```

Edit: I am also able to view dynamic route when I click on the link defined above and my URL section shows that long randomString. Problem is: I can access the same route when I search for `http://127.0.0.1:5000/update/1`

**Screenshot one**

[image]

**Screenshot two**

[image]

Comment: While storing the random string, the key you use is `randomString`. So you are storing the random string in a dict like `session['randomString'] = '1234567890'`. Then when you access the session in the `/update` route you are just checking if session has a key named `randomString`. You should also check if `session['randomString'] == '1234567890'` and render the page only if the random string in session is the same as you created in the `/` root. You can replace the if with `if 'randomString' in session and session['randomString'] == randomString`

Comment: You already have the random string as an argument passed to the update function → `def update(randomString):`. Just use that to check `if 'randomString' in session and session['randomString'] == randomString`. Remember that 'randomString' is a value whereas randomString (without quotes) is a variable.

Comment: Got it! Now it is working fine, thanks for your suggestion Akhil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While storing the random string, the key you use is `randomString`. So you are storing the random string in a dict like

```
session['randomString'] = '1234567890'
```

Then when you access the session in the `/update` route you are just checking if session has a key named randomString. You should also check if `session['randomString'] == '1234567890'` and render the page only if the random string in session is the same as you created in the `/` path. You can replace the if with

```
if 'randomString' in session and session['randomString'] == randomString :
```